# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'props'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. props in useEffect have no data

Tags: reactjs, redux

i used axios  to call api methods for data access in react hooks components .i used react redux for state management. i call the fetchall method from useEffect to get all courses. but the response array is empty and show above error.there is problem with state or props like that .or the course reducer does not fetch data .here is code of api.js in action.

```
import axios from "axios";

const baseUrl = "http://localhost:44306/api/"



export default {

    course(url = baseUrl + 'courses/') {
        return {
            fetchAll: () => axios.get(url),
            fetchById: id => axios.get(url + id),
            create: newRecord => axios.post(url, newRecord),
            update: (id, updateRecord) => axios.put(url + id, updateRecord),
            delete: id => axios.delete(url + id)
        }
    }
}
```

the courses components have 2 grids first Grid has been commented out to focus on problem. the second grid have table which should show courses in table. the backend table has many rows which has been tested with postman and from database. the courses.js is as follows.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import * as actions from "../actions/course";
import { Grid, Paper, TableContainer, Table, TableHead, TableRow, TableCell, TableBody, withStyles, ButtonGroup, Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import CourseForm from "./CourseForm";
import EditIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Edit";
import DeleteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Delete";
import { useToasts } from "react-toast-notifications";



const styles = theme => ({
    root: {
        "& .MuiTableCell-head": {
            fontSize: "1.25rem"
        }
    },
    paper: {
        margin: theme.spacing(2),
        padding: theme.spacing(2)
    }
})





const Courses = ({ classes, ...props }) => {
    const [currentId, setCurrentId] =useState(0)
    useEffect(() => {
        props.fetchAllCourses()    // here is error props is empty

    }, [])//componentDidMount

    //toast msg.
    const { addToast } = useToasts()

    const onDelete = id => {
        if (window.confirm('Are you sure to delete this record?'))
            props.deleteCourse(id,()=>addToast("Deleted successfully", { appearance: 'info' }))
    }





    return (
        <Paper className={classes.paper} elevation={3}>
            <Grid container>
                <Grid item xs={6}>

                    {/* <CourseForm {...({ currentId, setCurrentId })} /> */}
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={6}>
                    <TableContainer>
                        { <Table>
                            <TableHead className={classes.root}>
                                <TableRow>
                                    <TableCell>Title</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell>Details</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell>Category</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell></TableCell>
                                </TableRow>
                            </TableHead>
                            <TableBody>
                                {
                                    props.courseList.map((record, index) => {
                                        return (<TableRow key={index} hover>
                                            <TableCell>{record.Title}</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell>{record.Details}</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell>{record.Category}</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell>
                                                <ButtonGroup variant="text">
                                                    <Button><EditIcon color="primary"
                                                        onClick={() => { setCurrentId(record.id) }} /></Button>
                                                    <Button><DeleteIcon color="secondary"
                                                        onClick={() => onDelete(record.id)} /></Button>
                                                </ButtonGroup>
                                            </TableCell>
                                        </TableRow>)
                                    })
                                }
                            </TableBody>
                        </Table> }
                    </TableContainer>

                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Paper>
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    courseList: state.course.list
})

const mapActionToProps = {
    fetchAllCourses: actions.fetchAll,
    deleteCourse: actions.Delete
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionToProps)(withStyles(styles)(Courses));
```

the course.js in actions is as follows:

```
import api from "./api";

export const ACTION_TYPES = {
    CREATE: 'CREATE',
    UPDATE: 'UPDATE',
    DELETE: 'DELETE',
    FETCH_ALL: 'FETCH_ALL'
}

const formateData = data => ({
    ...data,

})

export const fetchAll = () => dispatch => {
    api.course().fetchAll()
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            dispatch({
                type: ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_ALL,
                payload: response.data
            })
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}

export const create = (data, onSuccess) => dispatch => {
    data = formateData(data)
    api.course().create(data)
        .then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type: ACTION_TYPES.CREATE,
                payload: res.data
            })
            onSuccess()
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}

export const update = (id, data, onSuccess) => dispatch => {
    data = formateData(data)
    api.course().update(id, data)
        .then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type: ACTION_TYPES.UPDATE,
                payload: { id, ...data }
            })
            onSuccess()
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}

export const Delete = (id, onSuccess) => dispatch => {
    api.course().delete(id)
        .then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type: ACTION_TYPES.DELETE,
                payload: id
            })
            onSuccess()
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

the course.js in reducer is as :

```
import { ACTION_TYPES } from "../actions/course";
const initialState = {
    list: []
}


export const course = (state = initialState, action) => {

    switch (action.ACTION_TYPES) {
        case ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_ALL:
            return {
                ...state,
                list: [...action.payload]
            }

        case ACTION_TYPES.CREATE:
            return {
                ...state,
                list: [...state.list, action.payload]
            }

        case ACTION_TYPES.UPDATE:
            return {
                ...state,
                list: state.list.map(x => x.id == action.payload.id ? action.payload : x)
            }

        case ACTION_TYPES.DELETE:
            return {
                ...state,
                list: state.list.filter(x => x.id != action.payload)
            }

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

why the useeffect does not access the props. how to access props in useEffect i will be very thankful for kind help.
the index.js in reducer is as:

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { course } from "./course";

export const reducers = combineReducers({
    course
})
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Seems like you need to pass the needed dependency to useEffect as mentioned in the error message.

```
useEffect(() => {
  props.fetchAllCourses()
}, [props.fetchAllCourses]);
```

UPDATE:
After reading the full error message in the comments, seems like you need to destructure the props:

```
const { fetchAllCourses } = props;

useEffect(() => {
  fetchAllCourses();
}, [fetchAllCourses]);
```

Comment: this did not work.the same error why does it not fetch the record ?very thanks for interest in my problem.

Comment: I think you mention multiple errors. The title of the question is about the missing dependency, but you also mention it does not fetch the record. Is your error about the dependency gone and you got stuck in another error?

Comment: no,@Orkun Tuzel the same error occured please help i have been in this trouble for the whole day.there is problem with state and props.useEffect() calls the function fetchAll but the data does not fetch.

Comment: this is the error:
./src/components/Courses.js
  Line 33:9:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'props'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. However, 'props' will change when *any* prop changes, so the preferred fix is to destructure the 'props' object outside of the useEffect call and refer to those specific props inside useEffect  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Comment: Can you please check my update in my answer? Hope that works.

Comment: the missing dependency gone but the data still not accessed is there problem with statetoProp method. ```const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    courseList: state.course.list 
    
}) ```

Comment: If you are getting the data (which you see in the inspector network tab) but it fails to represent the data, this maybe the problem: 
        ```case ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_ALL:
            return {
                ...state,
                list: [...action.payload] // try changing "list" to "courseList"
            }```

Comment: Also, if that doesn't solve your problem, I recommend you to create a new question in order to keep things in context. This question was about the missing dependency issue and the issue is fixed now. It's better to accept the answer if it satisfies you, and then focus on the next issue in another question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give dependencies to the useEffect, for it to watch.

Inside your Courses component, modify this bit

```
useEffect(() => {
  props.fetchAllCourses()
}, [props.fetchAllCourses]);
```

Comment: thanks for response @sv12 this did not work .the result list is still empty.

Answer (score 1):

The above answers did not fix the issue for me but simply adding props to the second parameter of useEffect() fixed the issue.

```
useEffect(() => {
   props.fetchAllCourses()
}, [props]);
```

Comment: Hi,dear @RAC ! it depends whether you destructure the props or not. like 'const { fetchAllCourses } = props;' you can use this .in my case it was like above.so ,@Orkun Tuzel answer worked for me.